# Angular: How to hide PrimeNG drop-down selected option?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I need my [p-dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) to hide the previously selected option.

For example, I have options `A`, `B`, and `C`. If I previously selected `A`, only `B` and `C` should show up in the dropdown list. Then if I select `B`, now only `A` and `C` should show up.

```js
//component.ts
this.planOptions = [
  { name: 'A'},
  { name: 'B'},
  { name: 'C'}
];
```

```html
//component.html
<p-dropdown id="plan_option"
  [options]="planOptions
  [(ngModel)]="selectedPlanOption"
  optionLabel="name">
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: what is if I have A, or if I have B, From where you get this infor ?

Comment: sorry i need to be more especific , i have an <a> where i show 1 o 2  depends on the plan, my dropdown needs to find wich one is the <a>

Answer (score 0):

You should create a copy of planOptions that contains only the possible options

TS File

```
copyOfPlanOption = planOption;
chosenOption: 'A';
const index = copyOfPlanOption.indexOf(chosenOption);
if (index > -1) {
  copyOfPlanOption.splice(index, 1);
}
```

HTML File

```
 <p-dropdown [style]="{'minWidth':'100%', 'width': '100px', 'height':'50px'}" id="plan_option" appendTo="body" [options]="copyOfPlanOption" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlanOption" placeholder=" "  optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can splice the options and then hide the `<li>` with css.

```
planOptions.splice(index, 1)
```

Then

```
.p-dropdown-panel .p-dropdown-items .p-dropdown-item.p-highlight {
          padding: 0px;
}
```